# Folder organization for easy translation

Tags: python, architecture, organization

I'm making an application in Python that will be released in different languages.

So I'm wondering what is the best way to organize a project so you don't have to look for literal strings in the source code and replace them by hand.

Here's what I have so far from some thinking and the information I could gather:

First we have a module for each language to contain every strings for the application:

english.py:

```
greeting = 'Hello world!'
```

french.py:

```
greeting = 'Bonjour le monde!'
```

then the code would be written so myModule.py:

```
if lang == 'eng': #How do you mimick a 'preprocessor' in Python?
    import english as str
elif lang == 'fr':
    import french as str

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print(str.greeting)
```

- Does it make sense to do it this way?
- Should every language have it's own module?
- How do you achieve the preprocessing conditionals of C in a pythonesque way?

I'm thinking there's no way it hasn't been asked before but maybe it's cuz English isn't my first language and I'm doing it wrong but I can't find any good info on the best practices to do this.

Comment: Well unless you want to reinvent the wheel, google python internationalization, There'e a version of I18n for the standard library at least.

Comment: looks promising I'll edit when I'll have read about it a bit

Answer (score 0):

My system is fu**** up but try this:

```
 import os
 lang = os.getenv('LANG')

 if lang == 'en_US,': 
    import english as str
 elif lang == 'fr_CH':
    import french as str

 if __name__ == '__main__':
    print(str.greeting)
```

I get None, but give it a try.